# Git. Rebase local branch atop local master. How do I ignore a single files changes?

Tags: git, rebase

With Git I am on a branch. I am rebasing the branch atop master. There is a conflict that I want to resolve by ignoring the branch's version and accepting master's version. How do I indicate I want to use master's version of the file during the rebase?

Comment: Currently on which branch you are in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git checkout --ours <path-to-file>` is the command you are looking for.

It will checkout the *master* version of the file which you then can add to the index (to mark the conflict resolved) and continue your rebase.

You can take a look at the [checkout documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for more information.

[See the comment under `--merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_options) as to why you need to use `--ours` and not `--theirs`.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want keep current branch file use `git checkout --ours filenamewithpath`
- If you want to keep other branch file use `git checkout --theirs filenamewithpath`

  Please check this link http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stucks as myself.

If you want to override all your local changes with "theirs", it is probably because someone removed a commit your local branch was referred to and added a new one and you're doing a rebase, so that git tries to apply (this old commit + yours) on top of theirs.

In this case use `git rebase -i remote-branch` and comment out the old commit.

Hope this helps.